# efficient way to get http status response code

Tags: php

Is there a quicker and more efficient way to check if a website shows status codes 200 etc?

Basically I want to check specific pages whether they're online of offline. Some of the pages I check go down sporadically with 502 errors, so I need a way to also make sure those are displayed as "offline" thus using the header response check.

when using the below function on say 5-10 pages, it slows the page loading time dramatically.

```
<?php
function getHttpResponseCode( string $url ) //: int
{
$headers = get_headers( $url );
return substr( $headers[ 0 ], 9, 3 );
}

if (getHttpResponseCode('https://www.google.com') !='200') {
echo 'offline';
} else {
echo 'online';
}
?>
```

**UPDATED CODE (not working atm) **

```
 <?php
function checkDomain($host) {

if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
  echo 'online!';
  fclose($socket);
} else {
  echo 'offline.';
}
}
echo checkDomain('https://www.google.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The speed should inprove considerably using this:

```php
$host = 'google.com';
if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
  echo 'online!';
  fclose($socket);
} else {
  echo 'offline.';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test it now and compare. How does this run with like 10 domains though? I need to copy that code for each one?

Comment: Just make a function and call that again and again

Comment: Thank you. For some reason the updated code I just added to my post is showing google as offline. Must of missed something. If you get a chance can you point me to understanding the parameters also? Just curious. Thanks again

Comment: Dang I cant figure this one out

Comment: Remove `https://` from `echo checkDomain('https://www.google.com');`, it'll work.

Comment: Yeah the above code just literally tells you if the site is "offline" or "online".

Comment: OR if you want `https`, you can use `ssl://www.google.com` instead and change port num 80 to 443.

Comment: ahh makes sense now. Ok..so there's no way to get it to check for http response codes? I have a few pages that occasionally go down with 503, so I need those to show as offline also...